# WebApi in-memory testing with multiple Web API projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing

I am using the System.Web.Http.HttpServer to spin up an in-memory server for use in integration testing of my Web API projects.

I've had a single Web API project, and a single Integration Test project in the solution. And this has worked fine.

Now I have added another Web API project to the solution, and when I add test for the new API controllers - then the test fails if test for both Web API projects are run in same test run.

If I run tests for API 'A' - they are all green.
If I run tests for API 'B' - they are all green.
If I run a test for API 'A' and a test for API 'B' in same testrun - the second test fails.

So somehow the configuration/settings bleed into each other - I just can't figure out why - and most important how to stop it.

I've read elsewhere that Web API finds the attribute routing by reflection and loading the assemblies - could this be what is happening - that both API's are in memory - and thus the routing fails? The second tests that fail gets an 404 answer back.

My tests are constructed like below

```
using (var config = new HttpConfiguration())
{
     config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

     ServiceA.AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
     ServiceA.WebApiConfig.Register(config, ImInvoiceService.ChooseAuthorizeFilter.Basic, addPerRequestHandler: false);

     using (var server = new HttpServer(config))
     { 
          var client = new HttpClient(server);
          var request = CreateWebRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "api/invoices");
          request.Content = new     StringContent(CreateJsonInvoice(purchaseOrder, overrideCurrencyCode: "XXX"), Encoding.UTF8, JsonContentType);

          var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
          Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
     }
 }
```

and

```
using (var config = new HttpConfiguration())
{
    config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

    ServiceB.AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
    ServiceB.WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    using (var server = new HttpServer(config))
    {

        var client = new HttpClient(server);
        var request = CreateWebRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "api/invoices");

        request.Content = new StringContent(CreateJsonInvoice(purchaseOrder, overrideCurrencyCode: "XXX"), Encoding.UTF8, JsonContentType);

        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

As shown in code, I create a new HttpServer, and a new HttpConfiguration in each test - leaving simple me thinking I get new objects.

I'm pretty stuck after trying to debug my way through this, I've tried to clear Routes, Config settings etc, but nothing seems to help.

I could create a new test project for the second API, but as this is integration tests, I depend of some setup - and will need to copy a lot of work to the other test project - and I would like to avoid that.

But if Web API/HttpServer can't handle two projects in same AppDomain that might be my last out.

Any good suggestions are welcome - I hope someone has a good idea.

best regards
/Anders

Comment: Try to use `TestServer` from _Microsoft.Owin.Testing_ [sample here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/26/unit-testing-owin-applications-using-testserver/)

Comment: I've tried - do I understand it correctly if that means I have to move my Global.asax.cs initialization to a Startup class to get this working? I've not used Owin much, but my current Web API project contains MVC help page as well - and I would like this to keep working.